# search exact string in string array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have a spinner. I want to get the value of the item selected and search the index of that value in another array.
This is what I have tried so far. s1 is the spinner. weapons is the array in which I want to search the value of the selected item in spinner s1

```
String[] weaponone = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weapons);
for (String s : weaponone) {
    int i = s.indexOf(s1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    switch (i) {
        case (0):
```

Comment: I don't get the question ..?

Comment: You say you're looking for an exact string in your string array
You don't define no constant for the value you're searching for in your array
You're doing a switch case on a int instead of a string ..

Comment: in first line i am defining the array, in which i want to compare the string i got by selecting item on spinner s1 in third line.

Comment: Please explain your question and specify what u need, try to get to the point.

Comment: did you face any problem?

Comment: yes problem is not solving..

Comment: what is not solved? did u failed to search ,  int i is getting wrong? what is the purpose of switch case? or is there any error?

Comment: yes int i is getting wrong. case 0 works well but all other cases are not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i got you situation ... in your case no need to use foreach loop focus on following example .. at first take a `arrays.xml` file under `res/values` folder
and declare `weapons` array like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="weapons">
        <item>a</item>
        <item>b</item>
        <item>c</item>        
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

and your java code look like this

```
String[] weaponone = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weapons);

    int i= Arrays.asList(weaponone).indexOf("b");   //i=1 for b, for a i=0 and for c i=2,if not found then i=-1 
        switch (i) {
            case (0):
               // implement your code 
                break;
            case (1):
               // implement your code 
                break;
            case (2):
               // implement your code 
                break;

           .................................


            case (-1):// when not matching 
               // implement your code 
                break;
        }
```

i hope it will help you.